# Is the POSIX "Technical Standard - Commands and Utilities Issue 4, Version 2" up-to-date?

Tags: shell, unix, posix, standards

I read the "Technical Standard – Commands and Utilities Issue 4, Version 2" by The Open Group from 1994 in great detail as that was the most recent documentation of the POSIX-standardized Shell Command Language I found. Now I'm seeing there've been updates to the POSIX standard going into the 2000s. I don't find the change logs clear. Now I am wondering: have there been updates to the given chapters 1 (Introduction) and 2 (Shell Command Language)? I found these excerpts from the P1003.2b Draft 12 Amendment:

> In addition to the Base Specifications, the Single UNIX Specification,
> Version 3 includes the X/Open Curses, Issue 4, Version 2
> specification. Updates to X/Open Curses, Issue 4, Version 2 have been
> limited to production of a Corrigendum to allow it to exist in a Base
> Specifications, Issue 6 environment.

What is this "Corrigendum"? Do I have to read up? Where can I find these specific changes? Do they change the content of chapters 1 and 2?

> This chapter gives an overview of the documents that comprise the
> different parts of the Single UNIX Specification, Version 3 and how
> they are organized. The Single UNIX Specification, Version 3 is made
> up of the Base Specifications, Issue 6 and X/Open Curses, Issue 4,
> Version 2. The Base Specifications, Issue 6 comprise Base Definitions,
> System Interfaces, Shell and Utilities, and Rationale.

Is there anything I have to read to update my knowledge about the Shell Command Language? I really want the most up-to-date information. I read some update logs, but they had no diff-like updates or similar.

Any help is much appreciated as I spent much time reading this standard up to this point and really want the certainty that my knowledge is also up-to-date on this topic now. Thanks!

Comment: weeeell is https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/ not enough?

Comment: Thanks for the resource. But as I said I wonder if what I read is up to date. The index of the issue 7 seems the same but is the content exactly the same? That’s what I’m wondering.

Comment: I do not really know what you expect... there is no diff between standard versions. If you want, buy all the standards and `diff` them. There doesn't seem a problem that you are solving. Mostly, updates to POSIX were fixing, adding `pthread_*` stuff, deprecating a lot of useless stuff. Your questions are too broad - `Do I have to read up?` I am in no position to tell you what to do. `Where can I find these specific changes?` in the standard, take two standard and make a diff of them.